# How to add a JList with JTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jtextfield, jlist

I have a menu (menu food ) and I put it in the Jlist 
but I want to add a JTextField to specify the quantity of a particular meal ( if I sellect a burger I want 2 from it )

so , How can I add a JList with JTextField ?
and if I want to add them in the Jpanel ?

Answer (score 0):

MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION this constant could help you to choose more than one selection

Comment: Could you elaborate?  How could you use it to solve the problem?  Can you give an example?  This is the seed of a good answer, but it needs more explanation.

Comment: Class ListSelectionModel (of package javax.swing)
declares selection‐mode constants
o SINGLE_SELECTION (only one item to be selected at a time)
o SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION (allows selection of several contiguous
items)
o MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION (does not restrict the items that can
be selected).

Comment: Edit that into your post; a usage example always helps. As it stands, this answer isn't very clear.  See: [How to answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: ok guys but if you have noticed that this is my first answer in this big site so help me to improve my answers to be helpful

Comment: This is a great reference with code: http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/introjb4/RadCH08.pdf